# How to use the . in the java class path while running

Tags: java, classpath

I want to run a java class in UNIX and my java class, `test.class` is inside a folder with the name like *test-java-1.0.1*.
So to run this java class I am using below command in UNIX:

```
$java -cp lib.jar  test-java-1.0.1/test
```

When I do this getting error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test-java-1/0/1/test
```

How can I use `.`in the java class path?

Thanks,
Eshwari

Comment: `java -cp test-java-1.0.1:lib.jar test` I think that should do it, but it is unclear what is the name of your class. Is it `test` and without any package deaclared?

Comment: yes. my class name is test and it is inside a folder test-java-1.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class is called `test` (without any package) and the resulting compiled class has been put inside a folder called `test-java-1.0.1`, then you need to mention that folder as part of your classpath and provide the name of your class to the java executable:

```
java -cp test-java-1.0.1:lib.jar test
```

On Unix, you can concatenate multiple classpath element with colon ':'. On Windows, you need to use the semicolon ';'.

Note to improve:

- Your class names should start with an upper-case letter
- It's always better to put your class inside packages.

For example

```
package my.nice.package1;

public class Test {
    // Your code here

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          // Do something
    }
}
```

And then to invoke your class:

```
java -cp test-java-1.0.1:lib.jar my.nice.package1.Test
```

Comment: @user3218187 Don't forget to mark your question as answered. ^.^

Answer (score 0):

You would wrap the path using quotations.

In your case, the command would be:

```
java -cp lib.jar "test-java-1.0.1/test"
```

Comment: It worked on my Debian box... Have you tried escaping your periods using \ ?

Comment: quotations also didn't work. still getting exception like  NoClassFoundError: test-java-1/0/1/test

Answer (score 0):

Look at below links on Compiling with Java & Javac. I have given answer there.

1. [Compile and run Eclipse Project from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902934/compile-and-run-eclipse-project-from-command-prompt/24381390#24381390)
2. [Java Command line operations Example](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=243)
3. [Build Eclipse Java Project from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line)

Hope this will help you to solve the problem.