# How to run a Java project from command prompt

Tags: java, qr-code

I have source code for QR code generation using Java.

I don't know how to run Java in command prompt.

**two jar files**

```
E:\QR Code\lib\core-2.2.jar

E:\QR Code\lib\javase-2.2.jar
```

**Java code path**

```
E:\QR Code\src\com\javapapers\java\QRCode.java
```

**Source code**

http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-qr-code

Explain me how to run the java in command prompt

Regards
Karthikeyan K

Comment: Did you [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+run+the+java+in+command+prompt&oq=how+to+run+the+java+in+command+prompt&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.439j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Build and run eclipse project from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441565/java-build-and-run-eclipse-project-from-command-line)

Comment: Anyone Know the Answer?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that Windows can find the Java compiler and interpreter:

1. Select Start -> Computer -> System Properties -> Advanced system settings  Environment Variables -> System variables -> PATH. ...
2. Prepend C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin; to the beginning of the PATH variable.

   Click OK

Then open command prompt and check if Java path setup done by below command

```
java -version
```

If everything ok it will show you which Java version you have installed .

then you can run java program Like below a example

```
C:\test> javac HelloWorld.java
```

I have `test` folder and it have `HelloWorld.java` file inside it after this

```
C:\test> java HelloWorld
```

It will give you output in my file i have added below content

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I done those things.  Please explaing all the steps?. Microsoft Windows Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\addcuser.MIN06100470LD01>java -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: Please dowload the code from that web and execute using command prompt. And send me the screen shot. http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-qr-code

Comment: Problem is i am new to java.

Comment: Its not a problem  you are new..problem is that you did not tried anything from google?

Comment: Boss this is simple example. Ok. I mentioned above example is have 2 . jar file that is the problem

Comment: Then you are not confirm what you have to ask? Because if u r making a new project then these 2 `jar` you have to put in `lib` folder of your project then you can use its classes.

Comment: ya ya. I created the project and used class. Its working in eclipse. I want to run in command prompt.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153057/how-to-run-a-java-project-in-command-line

Comment: another option create jar file of your project and then run from command prompt `java -jar yourproject.JAR`

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am working in SAP ERP. So can't run jar file directly. Please download and execute this code and send me the command prompt screenshot plz http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-qr-code

Comment: @Karthikeyan how will you learn ?  It easy search and do it. I am not free sorry

Comment: boss last 2 days I done the code in eclipse. still no idea in command pormpt. Please help me

Comment: you have already project in eclipse make its jar and run it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441565/java-build-and-run-eclipse-project-from-command-line

Comment: We have interface in SAP to JAVA via command prompt. in that interface jar file not working. Already i tried .jar file. SAP ERP have some restriction.